# Help with Collision of spawned object(postion fixed) with objects that there are translating on screen

Tags: iphone, collision-detection, lua, mobile

Hey guys I am creating a game using Corona SDK and so coding it in Lua. 
So there are 2 separate functions,

1. To translate the hit objects and change their color when they are tapped
   The link below is the code I am using to for the first function 
   http://developer.anscamobile.com/sample-code/fishies
2. Spawn objects that will hit the translating objects on collision. Alos on collision the spawned object disappears and the translating object bears a color(indicating the collision). In addition the size of this spawned object is dependent on i/p volume level. The function I have written is as follows:

   ```
   --VOICE INPUT CODE
   local r = media.newRecording()
   r:startRecording()
   r:startTuner()

   --local function newBar()
   --    local bar = display.newLine( 0, 0, 1, 0 ) 
   --    bar:setColor( 0, 55, 100, 20 )
   --    bar.width = 5
   --    bar.y=400
   --    bar.x=20
   --    return bar
   --end

   local c1 = display.newImage("str-minion-small.png")
   c1.isVisible=false
   local c2 = display.newImage("str-minion-mid.png")
   c2.isVisible=false
   local c3 = display.newImage("str-minion-big.png")
   c3.isVisible=false

   --SPAWNING
   local function spawnDisk( event )
       local phase = event.phase

       local volumeBar = display.newLine( 0, 0, 1, 0 )
       volumeBar.y =  400
       volumeBar.x = 20
       --volumeBar.isVisible=false

       local v = 20*math.log(r:getTunerVolume())    
       local MINTHRESH = 30
       local LEFTMARGIN = 20
       local v2 = MINTHRESH + math.max (v, -MINTHRESH)
       v2 = (display.contentWidth - 1 * LEFTMARGIN ) * v2 / MINTHRESH
       volumeBar.xScale =  math.max ( 20, v2 )

       local l = volumeBar.xScale
       local cnt1 = 0
       local cnt2 = 0
       local cnt3 = 0
       local ONE =1
       local val = event.numTaps
       --local px=event.x
       --local py=event.y

       if "ended" == phase then
           --audio.play( popSound )
           --myLabel.isVisible = false

           if l > 50 and l <=150 then
               --c1:setFillColor(10,105,0)
               --c1.isVisible=false
               c1.x=math.random( 10, 450 )
               c1.y=math.random( 10, 300 )
               physics.addBody( c1, { density=1, radius=10.0 } )
               c1.isVisible=true
               cnt1= cnt1+ ONE
               return c1

           elseif l > 100 and l <=250 then
               --c2:setFillColor(200,10,0)
               c2.x=math.random( 10, 450 )
               c2.y=math.random( 10, 300 )
               physics.addBody( c2, { density=2, radius=9000.0 } )
               c2.isVisible=true
               cnt2= cnt2+ ONE
               return c2

           elseif l >=250 then
               c3.x=math.random( 40, 450 )
               c3.y=math.random( 40, 300 )
               physics.addBody( c3, { density=2, radius=7000.0 , bounce=0.0 } )
               c3.isVisible=true
               cnt3= cnt3+ ONE
               return c3
           end
       end
   end

   buzzR:addEventListener( "touch", spawnDisk ) -- touch the screen to create disks
   ```

Now both functions work fine independently but there is no collision happening. Its almost as if the translating object and the spawn object are on different layers. The translating object passes through the spawn object freely.

Can anyone please tell me how to resolve this problem. And how can I get them to collide.

Its my first attempt at game development, that too for a mobile platform so would appreciate all help. Also if I have not been specific do let me know. I'll try to frame the query better :).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd like to help because I am using Corona for my current project, but you need to fix the formatting of your code in order for it to be readable. Off the top of my head I would guess the issue is function scope from all the locals you are throwing around, but I can't tell where blocks of code begin and end because of the screwy formatting.

Comment: (hint hint you've posted other comments but still not fixed your code)

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that the objects are all inserted into a group in the Fishies code. That is, your comment that they seem to be on different layers is correct. Note line 113:

```
group:insert( fishOriginal, true )
```

Physics don't work between display groups. This was done on purpose so that you can move the group around without affecting anything in the group, in order to do a moving camera like the Egg Breaker demo.

Comment: I guess that make sense. I didn't think of it at al. Thanks :).Ok but is there a way around this problem. Such that the object continue to translate and change color on tap but it all appears in the same layer (with the spawn object)

Comment: Insert all objects into the same group. So instead of calling "local group = display.newGroup()" for every object, you do that just once at the top. Alternatively you could just not insert them in any group, but it is handy to be able to transition screens and such by manipulating an entire layer.

Comment: I inserted it on top but its working fine.Firtsly its displaying only one object that is translating at a very high speed(much faster than what an individual object was translating). Secondly I want to play sound files that would be unique to each bubble. This is the main need for the game. Kind of like a jigsaw but using voice as well. Finally I would like to say thanks for trying to help me, as I this is for my semester project(individual project) and so a novice like me could really use some good help :).